# Python opencv screen recorder fps issue

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

I am making a screen recorder using `opencv-python` and it works but there is an issue with fps, the video is too fast and when I lower the fps the video speed gets slow, I don't really know what's the problem as I am a JavaScript dev, if anyone knows how to fix this i.e., get higher fps with 1x speed then please HELP!

my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui

def start_screen_recording():
    # Define screen resolution and frame rate
    screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()
    fps = 30
    bitrate = 6000  # Adjust as needed

    # Create video writer object for MP4
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')  # You can also use 'x264'
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, fps, (screen_width, screen_height))

    # Record screen
    try:
        while True:
            screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(screenshot)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            out.write(frame)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Release resources on Ctrl+C
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_screen_recording()
```

Comment: wrong library. opencv is for computer vision. use pyAV if you need to save video. learn about Presentation Timestamps (PTS).